# How to insert HTML in focussed textAngular element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textangular

I have multiple textAngular fields in same page with common toolbar and I have created a directive to auto insert some text in textAngular field at current caret position. Now the problem is I can insert the code when there is only one textAngular field. But with multiple textAngular fields, I am unable to find which textAngular field is focussed. 
Here is my code :

HTML

```
<div class="row mrgn20">
    <div class="formFld">
        <text-angular name="message" ta-target-toolbars="messageToolbar" ng-model="composeEmail.body"></text-angular>
        <text-angular name="emailSignature" ta-target-toolbars="messageToolbar" ng-model="composeEmailCtrl.emailSignature.text"></text-angular>
        <text-angular-toolbar ta-toolbar="[['uploadAttachment','bold','italics', 'ul', 'insertLink', 'fontSize', 'uploadImage', 'fontColor']]" class="toolbar" name="messageToolbar"></text-angular-toolbar>
    </div>
    <auto-insert-text options="composeEmailCtrl.autoInsertTextOptions" insert-in="message"></auto-insert-text>
</div>
```

JS

Controller

```
function ($scope){
  $scope.composeEmailCtrl = {};
  $scope.composeEmail ={};
  $scope.candidate = {
    name : 'Rahul',
    company : 'Test Company'
  }
  $scope.composeEmailCtrl.autoInsertTextOptions = [{
                title: 'candidate fullName',
                value: scope.candidate.name,
                key : 'candidate_fullname'
            }, {
                title: 'company name',
                value: scope.candidate.company,
                key : 'company_name'
   }];

}
```

Directive

```
app.directive('autoInsertText', function(textAngularManager) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span translate="insert_auto_text"></span> <span  ng-repeat="option in options"><button type="button" ng-bind="option.title" ng-click="insertText($event,option)" unselectable="on"></button></span>',
    scope: {
        options: "=",
        insertIn: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        var _editorScope = '';
        scope.insertText = function(event, option) {
            _editorScope = _editorScope || textAngularManager.retrieveEditor(scope.insertIn).scope;
            _editorScope.displayElements.text[0].focus();
            _editorScope.wrapSelection("insertHTML", option.value, true);
        }
    }
  };
});
```

The `autoInsertText` directive takes the insert options and the textangular field name in which the value is to be inserted. I want to support insertion in multiple textAngular fields depending on the current caret position.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a typo in the question, but you're passing in `$scope` to your controller but using `scope`.

Comment: @dewd corrected.. thanks for pointing it out